# Ckeditor - emojione plugin interferes with videodetector

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I use ckeditor 4 and these two plugins: [Emojione](https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/emojione) and [Videodetector](https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/videodetector). When Emojione popup is open first, the next time I try to add a video in the Videodetector popup I get the following error in the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null
    at detectar (VM2151 videoDialog.js?t=H8DA:4)
    at CKEDITOR.dialog.onOk (VM2151 videoDialog.js?t=H8DA:1)
    at CKEDITOR.dialog.<anonymous> (ckeditor.js:585)
    at CKEDITOR.dialog.n (ckeditor.js:10)
    at CKEDITOR.dialog.fire (ckeditor.js:12)
    at button.onClick (ckeditor.js:608)
    at button.<anonymous> (ckeditor.js:547)
    at button.n (ckeditor.js:10)
    at button.fire (ckeditor.js:12)
    at button.click (ckeditor.js:546)
```

This is the line in the javascript file:

```
function detectar(){
    var a=document.getElementsByClassName("cke_dialog_contents").item(0).getElementsByTagName("input").item(0).value,
        b="",
        c="";
    0<=a.indexOf("youtu.be")&&(c="youtube",b=a.substr...
```

Somehow the emojione plugin interferes with videodector and I don't know how to fix it. Could you please give me some suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. If anyone else have this problem here is how I fixed it:

Change `getElementsByClassName("cke_dialog_contents").item(0).getElementsByTagName("input").item(0)`

to

`getElementsByClassName("cke_dialog_ui_input_text")[0].getElementsByTagName("input")[0]`

in dialogue.js in Videodetector plugin folder.